# how to give a program permission to run without sudo?

Tags: gpio, permissions

I have a program, I wrote called "enc".The program is written in C, and reads GPIO pins, and thus requires sudo to run. but I don't want it to require sudo or a password to run. I tried `sudo chmod u+s enc` but it says

```
Unable to open /dev/mem or /dev/gpiomem: Permission denied.
  Aborting your program because if it can not access the GPIO
  hardware then it most certainly won't work
  Try running with sudo?
```

with sudo it runs fine, I just dont want users to need a password to run this program(enc).
Do I have to modify permissions of /dev/mem and /dev/gpiomem ?

Comment: What language?? `/dev/mem` and `/dev/gpiomem` are different animals.

Comment: If the program is compiled (so, not python), then you can use [`setuid`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid), see also `man 2 setuid`.  Make sure you understand the caveats WRT dropping privileges sooner rather than later.  The "not python" part is because you cannot apply this to any kind of interpreted script even if it is executable.

Answer (score 2):

`/dev/gpiomem` is usable by members of the `gpio` group.

Add the user running the program to the `gpio` group.

E.g. if you are running the program as user `joh` then enter the command:

`sudo adduser joh gpio`

You will need to log out and back in for the permissions change to take effect.

Comment: I tried this, but still get the same message

Comment: You need to edit your question and give specific details of the program you are running and the exact error messages.

Comment: the program is a program i wrote, its called "enc", and the exact error is shown., actualy, there was a typo in the word "certainly" which I fixed.

Answer (score 1):

`sudo chown root /path/to/program/executable`

and then I set its setuid bit with

`sudo chmod u+s /path/to/program/executable`

yes, security concerns, but honestly I think it will be fine, the interface is knobs and switches, all the data is integers between 0 and 255, without a keyboard or mouse, and not connected to the internet.  an alt could probably be done to run the program as root on boot as a service, but I'm not quite ready to do that.